# PERF STAT does not count memory-loads but counts memory-stores

Tags: linux, x86, intel, perf

Linux Kernel : **4.10.0-20-generic (also tried this on 4.11.3)**

Ubuntu : **17.04**

I have been trying to collect stats of memory-accesses using `perf stat`. I am able to **collect stats for memory-stores but the count for memory-loads return me a 0 value**.

The below is the details for memory-stores :-

```
perf stat -e cpu/mem-stores/u ./libquantum_base.arnab 100
N = 100, 37 qubits required
Random seed: 33
Measured 3277 (0.200012), fractional approximation is 1/5.
Odd denominator, trying to expand by 2.
Possible period is 10.
100 = 4 * 25

 Performance counter stats for './libquantum_base.arnab 100':

       158,115,510      cpu/mem-stores/u                                            

       0.559922797 seconds time elapsed
```

For memory-loads, I **get a 0 count** as can be seen below :-

```
perf stat -e cpu/mem-loads/u ./libquantum_base.arnab 100
N = 100, 37 qubits required
Random seed: 33
Measured 3277 (0.200012), fractional approximation is 1/5.
Odd denominator, trying to expand by 2.
Possible period is 10.
100 = 4 * 25

 Performance counter stats for './libquantum_base.arnab 100':

                 0      cpu/mem-loads/u                                             

       0.563806170 seconds time elapsed
```

I cannot understand why this does not count properly. **Should I use a different event in any way to get proper data** ?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: Hardware performance events are specific to the CPU used by you. What is the exact model? Not every possible `perf` hardware event is mapped to some real event (I think around half of them is not; some CPUs may have no raw L1 loads/stores counters at all). For intel CPUs use ocperf.py of pmu-tools https://github.com/andikleen/pmu-tools/blob/master/ocperf.py to encode real supported events into raw encodings of perf_event API (perf_event_open, `-e rXXXXX` event specifiers of perf CLI tool).

Comment: Hi @osgx, it is a Broadwell server CPU. The model is E5-2620 v4. It runs @ 2.10GHz. I will try using Andi Kleen's PMU tools to see if I can get memory-load events counted.

Comment: I have the same problem with a Skylake i7-6700HQ, so it seems like the `mem-loads` event is broken on this hardware on recent kernels.

Comment: Yes @BeeOnRope you are correct. IIRC I had to use a symbolic event value to obtain the memory-load events, I will update my answer as soon as I can determine the symbolic event number.

Comment: @ArnabjyotiKalita - cool, I look forward to it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `mem-loads` event is mapped to the `MEM_TRANS_RETIRED.LOAD_LATENCY_GT_3` performance monitoring unit event on Intel processors. The events `MEM_TRANS_RETIRED.LOAD_LATENCY_*` are special and can only be counted by using the `p` modifier. That is, you have to specify `mem-loads:p` to perf to use the event correctly.

`MEM_TRANS_RETIRED.LOAD_LATENCY_*` is a precise event and it only makes sense to be counted at the precise level. According to [this](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/mem_trans_retiredload_latency-events) Intel article (emphasis mine):

> When a user elects to sample one of these events, special hardware is
>   used that can keep track of a data load from issue to completion. 
>   This is more complicated than simply counting instances of an event
>   (as with normal event-based sampling), and so **only some loads are
>   tracked**.  Loads are randomly chosen, the latency determined for each,
>   and the correct event(s) incremented (latency >4, >8, >16, etc).  Due
>   to the nature of the sampling for this event, **only a small percentage
>   of an application's data loads can be tracked at any one time**.

As you can see, `MEM_TRANS_RETIRED.LOAD_LATENCY_*` by no means count the total number of loads and it is not designed for that purpose at all.

If you want to to determine which instructions in your code are issuing load requests that take more than a specific number of cycles to complete, then `MEM_TRANS_RETIRED.LOAD_LATENCY_*` is the right performance event to use. In fact, that is exactly the purpose of `perf-mem` and it achieves its purpose by [using this event](https://lore.kernel.org/patchwork/patch/688815/).

If you want to count the total number of load uops retired, then you should use `L1-dcache-loads`, which is mapped to the `MEM_UOPS_RETIRED.ALL_LOADS` performance event on Intel processors.

On the other hand, `mem-stores` and `L1-dcache-stores` are mapped to the exact same performance event on all current Intel processors, namely, `MEM_UOPS_RETIRED.ALL_STORES`, which does count all retired store uops.

So in summary, if you are using `perf-stat`, you should (almost) always use `L1-dcache-loads` and `L1-dcache-stores` to count retired loads and stores, respectively. These are mapped to the raw events you have used in the answer you posted, only more portable because they also work on AMD processors.

Answer (score 1):

I have used a Broadwell(CPU e5-2620) server machine to collect all of the below events.

To collect memory-load events, I had to use a numeric event value. I basically ran the below command -

```
./perf record -e "r81d0:u" -c 1 -d -m 128 ../../.././libquantum_base 20
```

Here r81d0 represents the raw event for counting "memory loads amongst all instructions retired". "u" as can be understood represents user-space.

The below command, on the other hand,

```
./perf record -e "r82d0:u" -c 1 -d -m 128 ../../.././libquantum_base 20
```

has "r82d0:u" as a raw event representing "memory stores amongst all instructions retired in userspace".

Comment: What hardware?  Not all CPUs have the same event numbers.  Also, that's a numeric event value, not symbolic.  On my Skylake i7-6700k with `perf` 4.15, `mem-loads` is also broken. 
 But [`ocperf.py stat -e mem_inst_retired.all_loads`](https://github.com/andikleen/pmu-tools) works.  (Note that that's only counting *retired* load instructions, not loads from the page walker or instruction-fetch, if `mem-loads` is supposed to count any of those.  And not loads from mis-speculated load instructions that never retired.)

Comment: Hi Peter,  these numeric events do indeed count the number of retired loads and stores. But the "retired store" event counts did match the actual number of `mem-stores` event. Whether this similarity would also apply to `mem-loads` or not I am not sure.

Comment: Yeah, probably `mem-loads` was supposed to be mapped to `mem_inst_retired.all_loads`, then.  The `ocperf.py` wrapper uses `perf stat -e cpu/event=0xd0,umask=0x81,name=mem_inst_retired_all_loads/`for that.  I didn't see an event for loads that includes page-walks and/or mis-speculated load instructions.  Hmm, I also don't see a specific event for `L1-dcache-loads` (which wouldn't include MOVNTDQA loads from WC memory, I hope).  Maybe it's another load *instruction* counter, not actually total L1 references.  Possibly synthesized from `mem_load_retired.l1_hit` + `..._miss` on Skylake?

Comment: Exactly Peter. I had the same concerns too when I was using the numeric event numbers, and I also looked into other sources of load events but did not find any event measuring them.

Comment: There are events for `dtlb_load_misses.miss_causes_a_walk` and `..._store_...`, but those don't tell you how many actual L1d accesses the HW page walker did, and how many it saved by keeping page-directory entries cached internally.  For non-retired stores, there's `uops_dispatched_port.port_4` (the store-data port).  Oh, stores never commit to L1d if they don't reach retirement, stopping speculative stores from becoming globally visible is part of the point of the store buffer >.<  It'd be cool to have an event for actual commits to L1d to measure merging adjacent stores in the store buffer.

Comment: But for speculative loads, `uops_dispatched_port.port_2` and 3 could help, except that store-address uops run on those ports, too.