# Running perf within a VirtualBox guest

Tags: linux, virtualbox, perf

My professor has asked me to run:

```
perf stat -e mem-loads,mem-stores ./test
```

In order for me to find the memory loads and stores for a C file. I'm doing this from within a VirtualBox Linux guest and problem is that `perf` is saying this is an invalid or unsupported event, can anyone advise as to what I'm doing wrong here?

```
invalid or unsupported event: 'mem-loads,'
Run 'perf list' for a list of valid events

 Usage: perf stat [<options>] [<command>]

    -e, --event <event>   event selector. use 'perf list' to list available events
```

Are `perf` hardware events available from within a VirtualBox guest?

Comment: It works fine for me (although, [suspiciously](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44466697/149138), `mem-loads` always returns 0, so that event seems broken) on Ubuntu 16.04. What is your kernel version and what does `perf list | grep mem` return?

Comment: Hey, when I tried that I got back this: mem:<addr>[/len][:access]                          [Hardware breakpoint] and kernel version: 4.13.0-32-generic

Comment: What does `uname -a` report?

Comment: Linux ubuntuHome 4.13.0-32-generic #35~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 25 10:13:43 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: How about `perf --version` and `grep -m1 'model name' /proc/cpuinfo`?

Comment: perf version 4.13.13

Comment: How about `grep -m1 'model name' /proc/cpuinfo`?

Comment: model name : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-7200U CPU @ 2.50GHz

Comment: How about `perf list | wc -l` ?

Comment: I hope we get somewhere with this lol, returned 10

Comment: How about `sudo perf list | wc -l` ?

Comment: ... and `cat  /proc/sys/kernel/perf_event_paranoid`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169117/discussion-between-jason-and-beeonrope).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With a [few exceptions](http://www.brendangregg.com/blog/2017-05-04/the-pmcs-of-ec2.html) (that don't include VirtualBox), you cannot use hardware PMU events in `perf` from within a virtual machine guest on Linux.

Perhaps there are lab computers that have native Linux installations, or you could use a bootable Linux flash drive to do you test. If your professor was the one who suggested a virtual machine in the first place, you could raise the issue with them.

Comment: Is this still the case? I am unable to get stats regarding branch misprediction or cycles. "Not supported" I assume it's because the VM running in virtualbox doesn't have access?

Comment: @Tony – could be, I am not up to date on VirtualBox support for PMU counters.